# JS nested array: How to display first array in console?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have this nested arrays.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];
```

I know how to access a property within an array like this:

```
contacts[0][firstName]
```

to get `"Akira"`. But I wanted to display the first array within the nested arrays. How do I do this? If I just type in `console.log(contacts[0]);` I get `[object Object]`.

I heard about JSON.parse(). Is it the correct way to display the first array within the nested arrays or any other array too?

Comment: No, I wanted to see in console the first array

Comment: There is no JSON there, so no need for `JSON.parse`. *Different browsers will show different output for [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)* (the link shows how to 'log objects' as well), so *consider [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) for diagnostic display of objects* instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print object array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895287/how-to-print-object-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `JSON.stringify()` instead of `JSON.parse()`.

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[0], null, '  '));
```

Answer (score 1):

If, on your data structure, `likes` is always an array, you can access it this way: 
`contacts[0].likes`

console logging it:
`console.log(contacts[0].likes)`.

You can also access every array by looping through the object:

```
contacts.forEach(contact => {
  console.log(contact.likes)
})
```