# Logging JavaScript arrays in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I console.log an array who contains objects in VS code terminal,

```
console.log(`new array is ${state.chats}`);
```

I get a result like that :

```
new array is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Instead of normal tree where you can see the objects inside like in Chrome Dev Tools :

```
new array is: [
{ sender: "joseph", message: "my text" },
{ sender: "daniel", message: "my text" },
{ sender: "joseph", message: "my text" }
]
```

Any way to "fix"/modify this behavior?

Comment: Can you show the array? Or a mock of one like it?

Comment: Hi, added the way it should look in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code's terminal uses a command line program like cmd.exe, powershell etc, these tools just put out the string values of your provided variable.

For `{ sender: "joseph", message: "my text" }` that would be `[object Object]`

One way to get the data as asked would be to convert it to a string with JSON.stringify.

`` console.log(`new array is ${JSON.stringify(state.chats})`); ``

Comment: Thank you, got it and working. 
Minor syntax fix: 
console.log(`new array is (${JSON.stringify(state.chats)})`);

Answer (score 0):

You must search by print array of objects in js.
At these link stay your answer ([How to print object array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895287/how-to-print-object-array-in-javascript/17512562)) you can use **JSON.stringify(yourarray)**.

For more information about go to: https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/JSON/stringify

```
var test = [{name:"pepe",age:21},{name:"juan",age:11},
            {name:"aurelio",age:31},{name:"evaristo",age:55},
            {name:"fermin",age:35}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: var test = [{name:"pepe",age:21},{name:"juan",age:11},{name:"aurelio",age:31},{name:"evaristo",age:55},{name:"fermin",age:35}];

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(test));