# console.log to print an arrays in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

```
const array=[{title:'Name',body:'My name is Hacker'},{title:'Age', body:'My age is 2020'}]
```

Given the above code, what is the difference between the following lines of code?

```
console.log('Items',array);
```

```
console.log('Items'+array);
```

Why is different output being printed to console?

Image link for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRQc.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print object array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895287/how-to-print-object-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This happen because when you use the `+` operator, you're converting the array to a string, concatenating `'Items'` with it and passing the resulting string to the first parameter. The array converts to `[object Object],[object Object]`, so the output is `Items[object Object],[object Object]`.

If you put the array in the second parameter, since the first parameter doesn't contain any format specifiers (`%s`, `%o`, etc...), most browsers will try to format the array with "optimally useful formatting" and print it after the string. Note that the [spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) does not require that behavior, as the [`Printer` function](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer) is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use console.table,
BTW the console.log("Items" +array) prints out "Items [object object], on the other hand console.log("Items", array) prints out the array content

Answer (score 0):

When you use concatenate any variable with string the result will be printed in the format of the string.

> **'Items',array**

in the above statement, there is no concatenation, so they print normally.
but when you use **"Items"+array** entire statement will be print in the form of string.